# Playing WoW on wireless DSL

Tags: world-of-warcraft

It's been awhile since I've played WoW but I'm bored and wanting to get back into it. However I'm at a 3 month temporary location (while I search for a suitable apartment). I'm on Wireless DSL connection with 2-3 Mb/s download and .5 upload. I have a strong signal (full bars always) and the internet is pretty fast.

I don't want to re-sign up for WoW if I'm going to lag like crazy. I have a **very** high-end PC so that won't be an issue; I'm more worried about being on Wireless DSL. I "could" make it wired, but I'd be dragging a 300ft cable through the house.

Will a wireless network connection cause significant lag when playing WoW?

Comment: I used to play over wireless. IMHO, your connection would be more affected by distance from the datacenter that houses your server than by you using a wireless connection over wired.

Comment: This makes me think about [this](http://danstonchat.com/12493.html) (french)

Comment: MMORPGs do not *require* a fast internet connections, like shooters or fighting games. Wireless should work fine. Furthermore Blizzard offers some trial period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a computer guy and a gamer, I've always preferred a solid wired connection. However, with wireless technologies such as 802.11n that isn't really that big a deal any more, even 802.11g is still suitable for good gaming. It depends on the router that you're using for the wireless broadcast.

Your ping times will definitely suffer a little bit when playing wireless instead of a cabled connection, but it won't be a bad choice. If you value a slightly (very small increase here) better reaction time, then a wired connection is the way to go. If you're not doing something that requires quicker reactions (i.e. Raiding Hard Modes) then wireless with be fine. Even if you are raiding hard modes it will still be fine so long as you're not in a top 25 world guild :P

Comment: It is wireless N, and distance is pretty small (IE it's like RIGHT above me, the router that is). Im in basement, router is a floor above,.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem then as far as distance is concerned since it is right above you. Side note: 300 ft of cable? Couldn't you just run it through the heat duct?

Comment: I was thinking that, im gonna check today.